# How to check the date format in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a date stored in string variable.
`$date = "26 Apr 2021"`

I want to check the `$date` is in `dd MMM yyyy` format
Return

---

if matches, else false

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am barely familiar with powershell. So, please take this sample as an example. Experts may be able to do it in a better way.

```
$date = "26 April 2021"
$isDate = $false

try {
    $parsedDate = ([DateTime]::ParseExact($date, "dd MMM yyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture))
    $isDate = $true
}
catch {
    $isDate = $false
}

Write-Output($isDate)
```

Comment: `ParseExact` will throw if the date format is invalid, you could use a `try { } catch { }` block instead of `if { } else { }`

Answer (score 1):

Use `TryParseExact()` that returns $true if the date is in the expected format, otherwise it's not throwing an exception.

```
$date = "24 Apr 2021"
[ref]$parsedDate = Get-Date

if ([DateTime]::TryParseExact(
        $date, 
        "dd MMM yyyy",
        [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,
        $parseddate)) {
    Write-Host "Valid date"
} else {
    Write-Host "Invalid date"
}
```